# Transforming values to columns and creating wide to long using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, where I would like to transform values to columns and creating wide to long using Pandas

**Data**

```
id  type    Q122    Q222    Q322
aa  hi      4       6       7
aa  hello   2       3       3
aa  ok      6       8       9
aa  bye     1       1       1
```

**Desired**

id    date    type    count

```
aa  Q122    hi      4   
aa  Q122    hello   2   
aa  Q122    ok      6   
aa  Q122    bye     1   
aa  Q222    hi      6   
aa  Q222    hello   3   
aa  Q222    ok      8   
aa  Q222    bye     1   
aa  Q322    hi      7   
aa  Q322    hello   3   
aa  Q322    ok      9   
aa  Q322    bye     1
```

**Doing**

```
a = df.set_index(['id', 'date']).rename_axis(columns='type').stack()
```

Looking to incorporate the counts in the final result as well

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: `df.set_index(['id', 'type']).stack().reset_index()`?

Comment: sure let me try this @It_is_Chris this works - thank you